# C++ lambda expression with "dynamic" body

Tags: c++, lambda

Is it possible to set lambda body from outside?

Example:

Classic lambda:

```
[](double x, double y) -> double { return x + y; };
```

What I want to do is something like this (to capture idea, this is not working code):

```
const char * const EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE = "x + y";

[](double x, double y) -> double { return EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE; };
```

Basicly I want to change string to "expression" in compile time.

Comment: is your variable a runtime or compile time value ? Does `#define EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE (x + y)` sufficient ?

Comment: The only thing I have in mind is to use virtual methods or `std::function` within the body of the lambda expression.

Comment: You can't create expression or statements run-time, but you can have multiple already compiled expressions or statements as functions (or other lambdas) that you can call depending on flag or state variables.

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? What is the use-case? Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: @Jarod42 It is compile time variable. #define is only one, If I use it in lambda, I would have to change it every time. I want to have multiple lambdas with different bodies.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Use case is more a study case, if it is possible and how. Real use scenario could be eg. some basic scripting

Comment: I strongly suspect that "lambda" is precisely what you don't want here. Raistmaj probably is right when he suggests `std::function`.

Comment: @MSalters I'd agree with that but wouldn't it be simpler just to replace the lambda with a `std::function` rather than the lambda being just a thin wrapper round the function?

Comment: @Component10: TBH the biggest problem is that the problem is horribly underspecified. In general the expression has a full parse tree, and realizing that parse tree will likely require an object tree to mirror the parse tree. But yes, the whole tree goes into a `std::function`, and there's no point in further wrapping that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible in pure portable C++11. I imagine that the `EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE` is only known at *runtime* (unlike your pseudocode). If it is statically known at *compile time*, use some macro tricks, generate (at build time) some intermediate C++ file and `#include` it, etc...

However, you may want to embed some interpreter (e.g. [GNU Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile) or [LUA](http://lua.org/)), or use [JIT compilation techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) (and libraries like [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), [libjit](https://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/), [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/), [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/), [asmjit](https://github.com/kobalicek/asmjit), ....) or even (like I'm doing in [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) generate C++ code and fork its compilation -at runtime- into a plugin and [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) that plugin, etc..

You'll need to understand a bit more about programming languages, compilers, interpreters. See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273827/40065) on *Programmers*.

Notice also that you could assign some [`std::function`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/) from a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You should capture this variable to the lambda using [] scopes and this will work even with not const variables

```
    const char * const EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE = "x + y";

    [EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE](double x, double y) -> double { return
    EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE; };
```

Or you can capture all variables that are available out lambda expression using the &:

```
    [&](double x, double y) -> double { return EXPRESSION_FROM_VARIABLE; };
```

Also you can use another types of capturing, for example

```
    [a,&b] // a will be captured by value, b will be captured by reference
    [this] // class pointer will be captured
    [&]    // all available symbols will be captured by reference
    [=]    // all available symbols will be captured by value
    []     // nothing will be captured
```